# Dynamic Columns in Flat File Destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working on a **generic SSIS package** that receives a flat file, add new columns to it, and generate a new flat file.

The problem I have is that the number of new columns varies based on a stored procedure XML parameter. I tried to use the "Execute Process Task" to call BCP, but the XML parameter is too long for the command line.

I search on the web and found that you cannot dynamically change the SSIS package during runtime and that I would have to use a script task to generate the output. I started going trough that path and found that you still have to let the script component know how may columns will be receiving and that is exactly what I do not know at design time.

I found a third party SSIS extension from [CozyRoc](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/data-flow-task), but I want to do it without any extensions.

Has anyone done something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of columns is unknown at run time then you will have to do something dynamically, and that means using a script task and/or a script component.

The workflow could be:

1. Parse the XML to get the number of rows
2. Save the number of rows in a package variable
3. Add columns to the flat file based on the variable

This is all possible using script tasks, although if there is no data flow involved, it might be easier to do the whole thing in an external Perl script or C# program and just call that from your package.

Comment: The problem I am having is on your step 3. How do I add the columns to the flat file dynamically?

Comment: I don't know: are you adding empty columns or columns with data? If there is data, where is it coming from? I would forget SSIS for now and work out the logic you need to implement; you can then decide to implement it using a script task or an external program.

Comment: Hi @Pondlife, this is the scenario: I have a stored procedure that can return,lets say, up to 3 columns X,Y, and Z. Sometimes a client just need X, another client needs X and Y and some other clients need X and Z. Do you think I can use a script task and pass only the input columns based on the SP parameters? 
Thank you.

Comment: @Jose Yes, that should work fine: a script task (or component) can do anything .NET can do. Alternatively, if the third-party component you mentioned does what you need, just buy it (I know you said you didn't want to, but you didn't say why).